# Apache NodeJS Cloudflare Sockets error

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, ssl, cloudflare

So, I've made a website which makes use of a SSL certificate and added Cloudflare free protection to it. Unfortunately, apart from the 443 port, every other port listed [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-) for HTTPS give an 523 Origin is unreachable error. Even when I stop Apache, it's still the same. Is there some misconfiguration involved? I will provide any demo or source code neccesary, as requested in the replies.

Comment: Is your website running on any of those ports?

Comment: Well, I've installed the ssl and now the site is accessible on 443, but I'd like to use one of the other ones for sockets. All I've done is set the socket to listen to that port for both the client and the server, is there anything else that I should do?

Comment: You mean you're running something other than HTTP on those ports? That won't work, CloudFlare can only handle HTTP(S) as far as I know.

Comment: But I see in the Network tab in my browser that a GET request is sent to https://example.com:2087/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M5VyH4n. Isn't that like any other HTTPS request, even if it's sent through sockets?

And, anyway, I used sockets before using HTTPS (that means on standard HTTP, on a cloudflare port) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: socket.io is different from sockets, you probably should have mentioned that. I don't know anything about socket.io sorry.